# PhpStorm indent settings (displays differently to GitHub)

Tags: php, github, phpstorm

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? The code looks different in PhpStorm vs GitHub

#### PhpStorm:

```
$sql = "Select 
                foo.bar1
                foo.bar2,
                foo.bar3,
                foo.bar4,
                foo.bar5,
                foo.bar6,
                foo.bar7,
                foo.bar8,
                foo.bar9,
                foo.bar10,
...
"
```

#### GitHub:

```
$sql = "Select 
                foo.bar1,
                foo.bar2,
                foo.bar3,
                foo.bar4,
                foo.bar5,
                foo.bar6,
                foo.bar7,
                foo.bar8,
                 foo.bar9,
                 foo.bar10,
...
"
```

Things I have tried:

- Changing tab size in settings
- Using smart tabs
- I can't use spaces
- Copying the whitespace from the line above
- Deleting the whitespace back to the previous line and letting PhpStorm handle indentation by pressing enter
- I am displaying whitespace and all the lines look like they're using the same amount of tabs
- Crying (only joking, that is next!)

Comment: `I can't use spaces ` -> why? Spaces are much better IMO - they're definitive, case and point: your question

Comment: @treyBake I don't disagree - it's for a code review and tabs have been deemed the standard. No-one is sure why this is happening. I think we will just call it gremlins in github and quietly walk away! :)

Comment: Do you have a link to that repository on Github?

Comment: @commonsense it's a private one sadly. What did you want to see?

Comment: Not something specific. Just wanted to investigate it by myself.

Comment: So far it sounds like some weird GitHub issue. Since you are using "Show Whitespace" option in PhpStorm, you should see if it's just tabs or if they are mixed with spaces. Few ideas: 1) try reformatting that piece of code (`Code | Reformat Code...` -- it may get rid of #2; 2) Ensure that you do not have any invisible unicode symbols there -- try **Zero Width Characters locator plugin**; 3) If all good there ... create a public repo with that single file (remove unneeded stuff but leave those problematic lines intact) -- maybe it's a GitHub issue...